Studying behaviour of a Klein-Gordon field inmersed in a classical electric field
I want to study the behavior of a 1+1 dimensional Klein-Gordon field immersed in a classical constant electric field, in the context of backreaction, i.e. I calculate the solution to the Klein-Gordon equation (after separation of variables)
$$
\partial_z^2 \phi_n = - (\omega_n - eA_0(z))^2 \phi_n
$$
calculate the resulting charge density after the proper renormalization
$$
\rho(z) = e \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} 
(\omega_n - A_0(z)) \lvert\phi_n\rvert^2 +
 \frac{e}{\pi^2} A_0(z)
$$
and finally calculate the resulting field this charge density generates, solving the Poisson equation
$$
\partial_z^2A_0(z) = - \rho.
$$
Reinsert this new electric potential into the KG equation and repeat until convergence.
Note this only works for smaller fields, otherwise you get divergences.
With this process one can calculate stronger field solutions by slowly varying the field and using the previous (converged) solutions as ansatz for the new field case.
After many of these calculations (and before Runge-Kutta breaks down) I get something like looks exponential dependence on the value of the induced field with respect to the external classical field.
The question is: how would one even begin to study or approximate this behavior to get this exponential dependence on the field strength? The equations are huge in their definition, they don't have a closed form and I don't even know how to start studying this from the differential equations.
Bonus question: This works by solving the coupled equations
$$
\partial_z^2 \phi_n = - (\omega_n - eA_0(z))^2 \phi_n \\
\partial_z^2A_0(z) = - \rho.
$$
independently. This means, solving the first equation whilst fixing the second one, and then solving the second equation while fixing the first equation. This is an obvious approximation. How would one study the limit in which this is approximately true? Of course this works as long as we are not too far from the equilibrium (converged state), but what does 'too far' mean?
